# Parsing Outlook Email Amount, Maturity and Beneficiary into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to pull data from emails in an Outlook folder through Excel VBA.

When I get to

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Amount:
```

I get an error message

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Sub FetchEmailData()

Dim appOutlook As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim iRow As Integer

Set appOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If appOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set olNs = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
'Clear
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Delete

'Build headings:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D1") = Array  ("Amount", "Maturity", "Beneficiary", "Size")

For iRow = 1 To olFolder.Items.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 1).Select

    '***This is where I get my error **
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 1) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Amount:

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 2) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Maturity:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 3) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Beneficiary:
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow + 1, 4) = olFolder.Items.Item(iRow).Size
 Next iRow

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can't see a **bolded area**. Why not add a comment on top of the line that throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of a late-binding technology is in use. You could prevent such errors in the case of early-biding. For example, the following code:

```
 Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Should be converted into explicit one:

```
Dim objOL as Outlook.Application 
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
```

To use early binding, you first need to set a reference to the Outlook object library. Use the Reference command on the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Tools menu to set a reference to Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library, where xx.x represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. You can then use the following syntax to start an Outlook session.

So, at the time of writing the code, you will be able to detect which properties and methods are available.

Read more about that in the [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) article.